# What's the meaning of "dangling a line" ?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idioms

In the song called [It Sure Took A Long, Long Time](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/lobo/itsuretookalonglongtime.html) by LoBo. I face this line:

*I'm sure it might have grown old

Like most young things usually do

and dangling a line to try and find your mind

For that I can't blame you.*

I really get confused since  how " **dangling a line**" can be good match for " **to try and find your mind**". Because if I use dangle as a verb, it has two  meanings:

(1)  to hang or swing freely

(2)   dangle something to hold something so that it hangs or swings freely.

Both of them seem illogical.

So I guessed maybe "dangling a line" is the idiom, I googled and still get nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "dangling a line" = "to go fishing" (I think).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the requirements of standard English are often not considered to apply to song-lyrics, which leaves one trying to second-guess the lyricist.

Comment: @Edwin but ELU does have a  [Lyrics](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lyrics) tag for "Questions about the words used in a song."

Comment: @Alan Carmack I missed that switch. It'll have to be 'opinion-based' from now on where applicable (note _Enrique's_ unacceptable 'In the context of the song it may mean ...').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a native speaker of English when I read that phrase "dangling a line" it brings to mind fishing. When you fish you let you the line dangle swing freely, as you say, to catch something.

In the context of the song it may mean that the woman had so much going on in her head that she did not know what to think. Trying to find her mind by letting the line dangle.

It seems she found it and wants to reconcile with the man who is singing the song.

Comment: You could also explicitly show the image of a woman trying to _fish_ her mind (lost somewhere in the river)